# Determine all the biholomorphic functions $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Determine all the biholomorphic functions $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

**My attempt:**
First, we show that $z_{0}=0$ is not essential singularity of  $g(z)=f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$, indeed, if $z_{0}=0$ was essential singularity of  $g$, then for $\varepsilon>0$ we have $g\left(B_{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}(0)\right)$ is dense in  $\mathbb{C}$, or what it is the same, $f\left(\left\{z\in \mathbb{C} \left|\: \left|z\right|>\varepsilon \right. \right\}\right)$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.\
For other hand, as $f$ is biyective, then $f$  is not constant, then, by the **open mapping theorem** $f\left(\left\{z\in \mathbb{C} \left|\: \left|z\right|<\varepsilon \right. \right\}\right)$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$, and as $f\left(\left\{z\in \mathbb{C} \left|\: \left|z\right|>\varepsilon \right. \right\}\right)$ is dense  in  $\mathbb{C}$, then:
$$f\left(\left\{z\in \mathbb{C} \left|\: \left|z\right|<\varepsilon \right. \right\}\right)\cap f\left(\left\{z\in \mathbb{C} \left|\: \left|z\right|>\varepsilon \right. \right\}\right)\neq \phi$$
but we know that $\left\{z\in \mathbb{C} \left|\: \left|z\right|<\varepsilon \right. \right\}\cap \left\{z\in \mathbb{C} \left|\: \left|z\right|>\varepsilon \right. \right\}= \phi$, so that $f$ is not *inyective*, which contradicts that $f$ is biyective.\
So that, $g(z)=f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ has not essential singularity in $z_{0}=0$, therefore, by a lemma derived from  **Casorati–Weierstrass Theorem** we have $=f\left(z\right)$ is a polynomial, therefore we have:
$$f\left(z\right)=a_{0}+a_{1}z+\cdots +a_{m}z^{m} \qquad \mbox{for some } m\in \mathbb{C}.$$

**My question:** I think that to conclude the proof I must show that every function of the form
$$f\left(z\right)=a_{0}+a_{1}z+\cdots +a_{m}z^{m}.$$
is biholomorphic, but for me it is not clear.

Comment: You quoted that lemma wrong. If $f(1/z)$ does not have an essential singularity at the origin then $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You are right.

Comment: You really think you can show that every polynomial is biholomorphic? How many solutions does $P(z)=0$ have, if $P$ is a polynomial of degree $n$?

Comment: We know that a polynomial $P(z)$ is holomorphic, the problem is to determine to which polynomials we have $P^{-1}$ is holomorphic, in that sense, one is tempted to think that such a polynomial must be of the form   $P(z)=a+bz$, but I must rule out all other cases.

Comment: Right. Now think about the question I asked. If $P$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ how many solutions does $P(z)=0$ have?

Comment: Already understood, the function  $f$ can't be a polynomial with greater $n>1$  because $f$ will have $n$ zeros, which contradicts that $f$ is injective. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lemma you want to use is probably the following

**Lemma** : If $f$ is holomorphic and injective on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{z_0\}$ and $z_0$ is not removable, then $z_0$ is a simple pole.

This allow you to state that $a_m =0$ if $m>1$. (Because $f(\frac{1}{z})$ is holomorphic and injective on $\mathbb{C}_0$.) Hence the biholomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ have the form $f(z) = az+b.$